# How to avoid using allow_any_instance_of on module instance method rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

I know using `allow_any_instance` is discouraged in Rspec, since it can lead to mixed/strange behaviours with all instances returning something we might not want

So for class I would do

```
let(:client) { Client.new } 
expect(Client).to receive(:new).and_return(client) expect(client).to receive(:method).and_return....
```

However, for module this wont work of course

```
module M
   method meth
     # do smth
   end
end
```

Method `meth` is called by another methods within module and I want to mock it in tests to simulate certain use-cases.

Is there any other way except of using

```
allow_any_instance_of(M).to receive(:meth).and_return...
```

Or it's simply fine to use allow_any_instance_of for mocking module methods?

Comment: Why not simply `allow(M).to receive(:meth)`? If `meth` is a module method then the receiver is `M` so you can just stub the method for `M`. `M` is a module and therefor does not have instances it is just `M` the module.